# Click on element after fading in on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a paragraph and an anchor, when i hover into the paragraph, the anchor fades in, how can I keep it for a little while so I can click on it? because when I move the mouse away from the p element it disappears and I cant click on it, here is my code:

```js
$(function() {
  $('p').hover(function() {
    $('a').fadeIn();
  }, function() {
    $('a').css('display','none');
  });
});
```

```css
a{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Show anchor</p>
<a href="#">Hi</a>
```

Comment: What if you put the `<a>` inside the `<p>`, then you wouldn't be triggering unhover by mousing over the a.  There are a few other ways to do it but that's probably the simplest, if acceptable.

Comment: You need to rethink your html syntax. Using jquery for this particular problem is not a solution. CSS is all you need.

Comment: @Matt can you give me an example please?

Answer (score 2):

As said in one of the comments by James, this is (i think) the right way

```js
$(function() {
  $('p').hover(function (){
    $(this).children('a').fadeIn()
  }, function (){
    $(this).children('a').fadeOut()
  })
})
```

```css
a {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Hello!<br>
  <a href="#">A Link!</a>
</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to animate minor things like drop down menus or fading links, you should use CSS. It's easier to write, and modern browsers are optimized to run CSS animations using the GPU (it's a CPU for graphics).

**This demo only uses CSS:**

- @keyframes for smoother transitions fade in and out with opacity values
- `pointer-events` in order to control how the link behaves. In this demo, the link will only appear if the paragraph is hovered over.
- padding and borders of paragraph and link are touching. This design allows the user to move the mouse over to the link without interruptions of the hover. There are dashed outlines to show the hover area only, they are for the demo and are optional.

### Demo

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font: 700 18px/1.2 Verdana;
}

a {
  display: block;
  padding: 1em .5em;
  border: 0 none rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: default;
  animation: out;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0s, opacity 4s ease;
}

p {
  margin-top:30px;
  padding: .5em
}

p:hover+a,
a:hover {
  border: 1em;
  pointer-events: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  animation: in;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0s, opacity 2s ease;
}

@keyframes in {
  0% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  33% {
    opacity: .33
  }
  66% {
    opacity: .66
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes out {
  0% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  33% {
    opacity: .66
  }
  66% {
    opacity: .33
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}

a {
  outline: 1px dashed red
}
p {
  outline: 1px dashed blue
}
```

```html
<p>Show anchor</p>
<a href="#">Hi</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `setTimeOut()` function. I have implemented this into your code: https://jsfiddle.net/kxt547zp/

Comment: what if i have multiple elements in this page with the same function? when i hover into one of them it ends the time session for the opened one, is that possible?

Comment: Cool, sure. It's possible using the clearTimeout method, you will have to run clearTimeout after a new element is clicked.

Comment: can you do it for me please?

Comment: @Jessica I'd recommend the most recent answer, based on what James said. It's cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/k8jkvbp5/

```js
$('p').hover(function() {
  $(this).next('a').fadeIn();
}, function() {
  $(this).next('a').fadeOut();
});
```

```css
a{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Show anchor</p>
<a href="#">Hi</a>
```

I've used `jQuery next` along with `fadeIn` / `fadeOut`

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in many ways like animation and delay. there I am using `delay` to overcome your issue may this help you.

```
$(function() {
   $('p').hover(function() {
        $('a').fadeIn();
    }, function() {

       $('a').delay(800).queue(function (next) { 

            $(this).css('display', 'none'); 
         next(); 
      });

    });
    });
});
```